# setImmediate inside setImmediate replacement

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a structure like this, it's an array of "operation" definitions:

```
{ 
 http1: {
   operation:"http", 
   params:{...parameters spesific to operation...},
   name:"http1",
   success: "sendmail2",
   error: "writefile3"
 },
 sendmail2: {
   operation:"sendmail",
   params:{...parameters spesific to operation...},
   name:"sendmail2",
   success: "http4",
   error: "writefile3",
 },
 ... and so on
}
```

almost all operations are actually functions that do async stuff inside (like http calls, and sending mail, reading file etc.) and takes the operation object above and a callback(next) as parameters, something like this:

```
function operation_function(operation_object, next){
  doSomeAsyncStuff(operation_object.params.x,operation_object.params.y, function(err,result){
    if(err){
       next(operation_object.error);
    }
    else{
       next(operation_object.success);
    }
  });
}
```

operations also pass the error or the results to next, or has possibilities other than success or error but i simplified them for this question.

now there is a function that runs these opertaions(simplified here), operation functions is a `require`d file of the operations.

```
function runOperations(operation_list,operation_name,result_callback){
   let operation = operation_list[operation_name];
   //this is the operation function above
   operationFunctions[operation.operation](operation, function (next_operation){
      //this is the next function
      if(!nextOperation){
        result_callback();
      }
      else setImmediate(runOperations,operation_list,next_operation,result_callback);
   });
}
```

There is a special operation named start, that just points to another operation, i call runOperations inside an http server request handler, get the operation_list name from the request parameters, get the list from database and call the runOperations with the start operation, with the callback being writing a response to the http request.

My question is that i can't recursively call runOperations, or directly call the next_operation's function in place of setImmediate because operation_list may be long enough to result in a "maximum call stack size reached".

setImmediate solves that but i think there has to be a better way other than setImmediate here. process.nextTick is mostly no-go because there are a couple of sync functions, and there is a non-zero possibility of syncronously calling process.nextTick multiple times and starve the event loop.

My main problem is that this thing lives in a http server request handler and multiple different operations may be running at the same time, setImmediate seems to have a performance impact while running multiple operations(handling multiple requests at the same time).

Any guidance is be appreciated.